# How to encode japanese character in oracle Sql developer?

Tags: oracle11g

I'm using oracle sql developer. Version is (1.5.5). I was tried to store japanese character in database. Running script is success. But I couldn't see japanese character in sqlresult.And I already set in environment variable NLS_LANG as ENGLISH_FRANCE.JA16SJIS. And encoding is SHIFT_JIS. How to solve?

Comment: What data type are you using to store the data?  What is your database and national character set?  Have you used the `dump` function to see what is actually stored in the database to determine whether the problem occurs storing or retrieving the data?

Comment: @JustinCave ⇒　Yes, data type is varchar2 And database is oracle. I think, character set will be default value. because, I didn't change in installation time. Actually store data is ???

Comment: There are many, many possible character sets that could have been defaulted at installation time.  Not many of them support Japanese characters.  What does `v$nls_parameters` tell you the database character set is?

Comment: Hello @JustinCave ⇒　I'm window user!

Comment: I'm not sure what Windows has to do with anything.  `v$nls_parameters` is a database table.  If you query it, it will tell you what character set your database is using.  You'd use that table whether the database is running on Windows or Unix or anything else.

Comment: @JustinCave⇒ yes, character set is "JA16SJIS".

Comment: OK.  Have you used the `dump` function to see what is actually stored in the database?  Are you certain that the binary value being stored is what you expect and that the problem occurs during retrieval?